# WPF Style ListBox with ItemStyle and DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate

I'm using WPF 4.5.2 and .Net 4.7.2

My base style looks like this

```
<Style x:Key="MyListBoxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >

    <Setter Property="Template">

        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"     />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">

                        <TextBox    Text="{Binding MyText}" />

                    </Border>


                    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">

                        <ContentPresenter />

                    </Border>

                </Grid>


            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>

</Style>
```

furthermore, there are several DataTemplates looking something like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeDataTemplate">

    <TextBox    Text="{Binding SomeString}" x:Name="txtContent"  Style="{DynamicResource MyStyle}" />

</DataTemplate>
```

I'm using a DataTemplateSelector class. Everything is recognized correctly, so there isn't any issue in terms of setting the ItemContainerStyle or the DataTemplateSelector.

But the style of the TextBox in the ControlTemplate of the ListBoxItem should be changed as well as the style the TextBox in the DataTemplate.

Is that possible or do I have move the ControlTemplate entirely to the DataTemplate?

Comment: Data related controls, i.e. controls that bind to the item's `DataContext` should go to the `DataTemplate` which is then applied to the `ContentPresenter` of the `ControlTemplate`. But beside this you can assign a `Style` to the `TextBox` inside the `ControlTempolate` too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But to apply different Styles to the Controltemplate, I would have to create an extra style for a ListBoxItem for each style that's needed in the ControlTemplate, wouldn't I?

Comment: I not sure if I understand you. First of all you should move the `TextBox` from the `ControlTemplate` to the `DataTemplate`. But to me it sounds like you want to change the `Style` of the `TextBox` inside the `ControlTemplate` baes on some conditions. One way to achieve this is to add a `DataTrigger` to `ControlTemplate.Triggers` property and set the `TextBox.Style` accordingly. What are the conditions?

Comment: It's the question what is best practice. I need both of the TextBoxes. I could achieve, what I want through the usage of different styles of the ListBoxItem or through one style of the ListBoxItem and different DataTemplates. Anyhow both of the TextBoxes have to change their styles dynamically based on a property in the ViewModel (of the ListBoxItem). I was wondering if there is a way keep the layout of the Grid of if it's neccessary to repeat the Grid layout for each possible DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to move all data related controls, i.e. controls that bind to the item's `DataContext` to the `DataTemplate`. Then use a `DataTrigger` to switch between different styles that targets the `TextBox`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeDataTemplate">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtContent" 
             Style="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}" />

    <TextBox x:Name="OtherTxtContent"
             Style="{StaticResource OtherDefaultStyle}" />
  </StackPanel>


  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="True" >
      <Setter TargetName="TxtContent" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource AlternativeTextBoxStyle}" />
      <Setter TargetName="OtherTxtContent" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource OtherAlternativeTextBoxStyle}" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, the DataTrigger was the missing piece.